# iOS 7 During partial curl transition the navigation bar turns white

Tags: ios, curl, navigation, transition

Since i changed my Storyboard from iOS 6 to iOS 7 i have the following problem.
The navigation bar changes during the partial curl transition to white.
I just took a screen recording for better understanding. I have the same problem in my app on a device.

Video: [partial curl transition](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uzzaq64edprf0os/PartialCurl.mov)

Any suggestions?

Comment: post your code or screen shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer! you have to set at your root view controller (where the action to the partial curl triggers) extend edges under top bar!

Answer (score 0):

Because in ios7 navigationBar color should taken from view background color

```
 -(void)viewDidDisapper{

     self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];// Your nav image
    }

 -(void)viewWillDisapper{

     self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];// Your nav image
    }
```

or set your appdelegate in case your common UINavigation Bar image throughout project

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor barColor]];
```

Comment: thanks but it is not working. still the same problem. i set the tint color on both controller on the did-,willappear and disappear with your code. not working :/

Comment: i have set the tint color in the interface builder on the root navigation controller

Comment: thats my storyboard
http://s14.directupload.net/images/140122/h9n6mo6b.png
when i recreate a similar situation in a new project it is working perfectly.

Comment: did you hide navbar in your curl transaction controller